# Perl to Java communication using RMI?

Tags: java, perl, jvm, rmi, perl-module

Am I able to use RMI to communicate between A JVM and another JVM that's been created by Inline::Java???
The functionality I'm looking for is basically to be able to communicate with an external running JVM from Perl, and i'm wondering whats the best way to do this.

Comment: I worked on a project around this same use case a few years ago - the problem is that JVMs are deliberately isolated from each other unless they are being controlled by the same container, and even then most items of interest are tightly encapsulated. You might consider messaging and/or http/TCP invocations to accomplish what you want.

Comment: @Ionstar I don't know why you think that's a problem. It isn't. That's what RMI is *for.*

Comment: The use case was slightly different - the Perl and external JVM were on separate servers. Cross-server RMI at a professional software company is an exercise in network change ticket escalation I can't recommend for anyone except people who post RTFG responses or delete newbie questions on SO. If you are on the same localhost, fine, but if you are cross-server you're better off using messaging with generally permitted ports.

Comment: @lonstar Your unstated administrative difficulties are your own. I am using inter-JVM RMI across the Internet from India to private JVMs inside private JVMs inside a server in California. It can be done.

Comment: Does anyone know how i can run RMI with the client class inside Inline::Java?

Comment: As nobody here knows what's stopping you, the question in unanswerable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, that's exactly what RMI is for: inter-JVM communication.